# Codeigniter issue when using static property in a class

Tags: codeigniter, methods, properties, static, controller

I had an issue when using a static class property within CodeIgniter framework.
*I use the current 'Welcome_message' view for debugging purpose only by using an array as input of the class.*

I would like to use a private static property called 'data' to be used by different class functions (in a same Controller).
See my code below:

```
<?php class Test_dev extends CI_Controller
{
  private static $data='';

  public function change()
  {
    self::$data= array('test1'=>'data1','test2'=>'data2');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',array('output'=>self::$data));
  }

  public function check()
  {
     $this->load->view('welcome_message',array('output'=>self::$data));
  }
}
?>
```

When calling the method 'change' in my Controller ***/test_dev/change*** I've got the good behavior, the static $data property is modified and retrievable.
I obtain:

> array(2) { ["test1"]=> string(5) "data1" ["test2"]=> string(5) "data2"
>   }

**But** when using the method 'check', ***/test_dev/check***, I only get the initialized value of $data.

> string(0) ""

I was expacting to get also the first result by using the 'check' method. I don't know what's wrong in my code to retrieve the static property in different methods.
Thanks for your support!
Erwann

Comment: Hi Smokehouse, sorry may I miss some points: when using first the 'change' function I assumed that $data will be changed by the code 'self::$data= array('test1'=>'data1','test2'=>'data2');' and retrieve these values then when using the 'check' function.
But the 'check' function gives the initialized value of $data and not the one given in the 'change' function as I was exepected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution by using Cookie Helper in CodeIgniter to pass and retrieve the variable $data.
See my final code:

```
<?php
class Test_dev extends CI_Controller
{
 private static $data='';

 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
 }

 public function change()
 { 
    self::$data= array('test1'=>'data1','test2'=>'data2');
    set_cookie('test',serialize(self::$data),time()+3600);
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',array('output'=>self::$data));
 }

 public function check()
 {
    $test = unserialize($_COOKIE['test']);
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',array('output'=>$test));
 }
}
?>
```